# Python Pickle gives EOFError when using loads with data read from sql table

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to load a BLOB saved field - embedding after reading the same from mysql using the code below :

```
try:
    print("executing query >> " + str(sql))
    cursor.execute(sql)

    for tag, embedding in cursor.fetchall():
        result['TAG'] = tag
        result['EMBEDDING'] = pickle.loads(embedding)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/sql_test.py", line 44, in get_existing_embeddings
  result['EMBEDDING'] = pickle.loads(emb)
  EOFError: Ran out of input
  File "/home/xxx/SETUP/pycharm-community-2018.2.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
  main()
```

Ran out of input

However, while debugging I can see that embedding variable is not empty : Attached snapshot :

[image]

Code to save the BLOB field :

```
data["EMBEDDING_DATA"]=numpy.array(image_embedding).dumps()
..
.
sql_stmt="INSERT INTO "+DatabaseCredentials.DATABASE+"."+DatabaseCredentials.EMBEDDING_TABLE_NAME
sql_stmt = sql_stmt + " (TAG ,DOMAIN,PICTURE_ID,IMAGE_PATH,EMBEDDING_DATA,EMBEDDING_BASE_RESOLUTION,CREATED_AT,STATUS) "
sql_stmt = sql_stmt + " VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
args = (data["TAG"],
        data["DOMAIN"],
        data["PICTURE_ID"],
        data["URL"],
        data["EMBEDDING_DATA"],
        data["EMBEDDING_DATA_RESOLUTION"],
        now,
        data["STATUS"]
        )
try:
    cursor.execute(sql_stmt,args)
    res = db.commit()
except connector.errors as e:
    print(e)
```

I can see this data when querying the sql table as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that blob field in the sql table was falling short for the pickle dump that I was trying to save. I altered the column in the sql table to longblob and now it is working correctly.